# How to add multiple Simplemessagelistenercontainer dynamically through application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Below is our program, we create multiple containers for different queue through property in application.properties. But now it is static, when add another property, we must change the code.

I want add containers dynamically. I investigate several solutions.

1.use BeanFactory.registerSingleton method, but it cannot receive lifecycle callback,so i'm not sure the container can shutdown gracefully.

2.use BeanFactoryPostRegistor, but it need build a BeanDefinition, i have no idea how can construct a BeanDefinition for SimpleMessageListenerContainer, because it will be created by SimpleMessageListenrContainerFactory.

Can anybody give me better solution both add beans dynamically and the SimpleMessageListenerContainer can be started and shutdown normally?

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.kvm")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer kvmReplyQueueConsumer() {
    return getSimpleMessageListenerContainer(environment
            .getProperty("pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.kvm"));
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.vmware")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer vmwareReplyQueueConsumer() {
    return getSimpleMessageListenerContainer(environment
            .getProperty("pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.vmware"));
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.powervc")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer powervcReplyQueueConsumer() {
    return getSimpleMessageListenerContainer(environment
            .getProperty("pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.powervc"));
}



@Autowired
private SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;

private SimpleMessageListenerContainer getSimpleMessageListenerContainer(String queueName){
return simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.createContainerInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take all properties you need (for example by regexp) and then register beans you want. There are 2 separate task there (1) how to get Spring properties (2) how register bean dynamically

1)  To iterate over properties in 'Spring way':

```
@Autowired
Properties props;
....
for(Entry<Object, Object> e : props.entrySet()) {
    if( /*some code to match*/ ){
       //dispatch bean creation
    }
}
```

2) you can either create beans dynamically by:

```
public MyClassPostRegister implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        //create bean definition:
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(MyBeanClass.class);
        beanDefinition.setLazyInit(false);
        beanDefinition.setAbstract(false);
        beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
        beanDefinition.setScope("prototype");
        beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("dynamicBean",beanDefinition);
}
```

**Appendix after comment @GrapeBaBa**:

*Actually I use simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.createContainerInstance() to create container, so how to transform to use beanDefinition* - please pay attention to lines marked with (!!!)

Create you own component

```
@Component
public class MyClassPostRegister implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
@Autowired 
Properties props; //this gives you access to all properties
//following is example of filter by name
static final Pattern myInterestingProperties = 
   Pattern.compile("pmc\\.multiple\\.hypervisor\\.reply\\.routerkey\\..+");
```

Add post-process handler:

```
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    //iterate through properties
    for(Entry<Object, Object> e : props.entrySet()) {
        Matcher m = myInterestingProperties.matcher(e.key);
        if( !m.matches() )
            continue;
        //create bean definition:
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class);
        beanDefinition.setLazyInit(false);
        beanDefinition.setAbstract(false);
        beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
        beanDefinition.setScope("prototype");
        //!!! Now specify name of factory method
        beanDefinition.setFactoryMethodName("getSimpleMessageListenerContainer");
        //!!! Now specify factory arguments:
        ConstructorArgumentValues v = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
        v.addGenericArgumentValue( e.getKey() ); //string 
        beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().add( v );

        beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("dynamicBean",beanDefinition);            
    }
```

}

Comment: yes, i know this method, but how to create beandefinition for simplemessagelistenercontainer?

Comment: Actually I use simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.createContainerInstance() to create container, so how to transform to use beanDefinition.

Comment: Just check my new edits, sorry have no java compiler right now to check